# Android Check internet connection broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to check the internet connection. I wrote a class which can check the internet connection.
This is the source:

```
public class ConnectionDetector {

private Context _context;

public ConnectionDetector(Context context) {
    this._context = context;
}

public boolean isConnectingToInternet() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity != null) {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }

    }
    return false;
}



if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
                alert.showAlertDialog(CameraPreview.this,
                        "no!");
            } else {

                alert.showAlertDialog(CameraPreview.this,
                        "yes!");
            }
```

At the moment the code is working fine, but I want to use `BroadcastReceiver`  to check the internet connection. How can I rewrite the code to check the internet connection every time (I mean `BroadcastReceiver` ).

Comment: why do you need a broadcast receiver to check for the internet? if you do that you will also need some way to send back a true false which seems like a lot of unnecessary complexity when you have it already

Comment: [Have you searched at all](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=broadcast+receiver+internet+connection%5Bandroid%5D)?

Comment: i have Asynctask class to upload video to server.video's size is large.and i want to check internet connection.i want to broadcast receiver  because if asynctask has start and  internet connection  disabled  i want simple alert message